# How to pass data between views. When should I use what?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, inheritance, parent-child

I have a View-Hierarchy like this:

> - UIViewController (**SingleEventViewController**)
>
>   - UIScrollView    (**EventScrollView**)
>
>     - UIView      (**contentView**)
>
>       - 3xUITableView (SurePeopleTV, MaybePeopleTV, NopePeopleTV (all inherited from the same UITableView)), & all other UI-Elements

The SingleEventViewController stores one Event (passed within the initializer). (All Events are stored in Core-Data).

The three `UITableViews` are there for displaying the users which are participating (or not or maybe) at the Event. My question is, what are the possibilities to fill the tableViews with the data and what would you recommend in which situation.

---

Currently I have a property `parentVC: SingleEventViewController` in all Subviews and get the data like this:

```
override func loadUsers() {
//class SurePeopleTV
    guard let parentController = parentVC else { return }
    users = (parentController.thisEvent.eventSureParticipants?.allObjects as! [User])
    finishedLoading = true
    super.loadUsers()
}
```

.

```
func applyDefaultValues() {
//class EventScrollView
    guard let parent = parentVC else { return }
    titleLabel.text = parent.eventName
}
```

I'm new to programming but I got a feeling that I should not create a parentVC reference in all of my classes.

Answer (score 2):

An object should not (ideally) know about its parent - if it does they are "tightly coupled". If you change the object's parent, your code may break. In your case, your parent object must have a `thisEvent` property.

You want your objects to be "loosely coupled", so the object doesn't know about a specific parent object.

In Swift, the usual ways to pass information "back up the chain" is to use the delegate design pattern… https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns or to use closures.

See also https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/04/08/how-delegation-works-a-swift-developer-guide/ for info on delegation

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am passing information "down the chain" so should I pass the whole Event with it or would something like the "loosely coupled" thing make more sense?

Comment: A view controller can know about and pass model objects to its views - but use delegation for passing or requesting information from back up the chain (from view to view controller)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you create a reference to the parent ViewController make sure it is weak, otherwise you can run into memory management issues.

**Edit:** As Ashley Mills said, delegates the way to handle this

<del>The recommended way to pass data between ViewControllers is using something like this</del>


<del>Every time a segue is performed from the view controller this function is in this function is called. This code first checks what identifier the segue has, and if it is the one that you want, you can access a reference to the next view controller and pass data to it.</del>

Comment: But I'm not passing data to a new ViewController. I'm passing data between Subviews of the same ViewController. Also I don't work with storyboards at all because my Company does everything in code.

Comment: Ashley Mills answer is better for your situation then